# adding text to a kml icon

Tags: kml

I have a document with many placemarks. Each placemark is a bicycle station, and I have to show how many bikes are in the station. Is there a way to add text to the placemark icon?
(I'm aware I can put this data in the balloon, but I really need to add this to the Icon)

Thanks,
Ami

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way would be to change the icon file you are pointing to based on the number of bicycles at that location. You could use icons like these a MapIcons http://mapicons.nicolasmollet.com/numbers-letters/

Comment: Thanks, I ended up doing this.

Answer (score 0):

The general answer is KML supports [LabelStyle](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#labelstyle) which allows you to style the  displayed.

The other option is to create custom markers with the numbers associated with them.

Other options would depend on how you are displaying the kml.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :-)
It seems I can't add text to the label with labelStyle, or am I missing something?